# Sqlalchemy: many-to-many joining field where field=max and extra fields

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a set of tables that look like:

```
Inputs =========  Parts ========= Outputs
        (n, m)     ||     (n, m) 
                   ||
                 (n, m)
                   ||
                   ||
               Productions

class Input(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'inputs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    some_attr1 = Column(Unicode(length)
    some_attr2 = Column(Unicode(length)

class Output(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__  = 'outputs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    some_attr1 = Column(Unicode(length)
    some_attr2 = Column(Unicode(length)
    extra_attr1 = Column(Unicode(length)
    parts = relationship('Part', backref='output', 
                         passive_deletes='all', 
                         passive_updates=True)

class Part(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'parts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    id_input = Column(ForeignKey('inputs.id'))
    id_output = Column(ForeignKey('outputs.id'))
    extra_attr = Column(Unicode(length))

class Production(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'productions'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    date = Column(DateTime, default=get_current_time)
    flag = Column(Boolean)
    other_attr1 = Column(Unicode(length))
    parts = relationship('Parts',
                         secondary="productionsteps",
                         backref=backref("productions", lazy='dynamic'))

productionsteps = Table('productionsteps', 
                        BASE.metadata,
                        Column('id_production', 
                               Integer, 
                               ForeignKey('productions.id)),
                        Column('id_part', 
                               Integer, 
                               ForeignKey('parts.id')),
                        UniqueConstraint('id_production',
                                         'id_part',
                                         name='uix_productionsteps'))
```

I am trying to query the latest 'productions' of each output subsets (production of a group of parts associated to an output) where the production dates are lower than DATE1 and the productions flags equal to BOOL1.

1/ Get the latest production of each output older than DATE1

```
subquery1 = (
    session.query(Output.id.label("id_output"),
                  func.max(Production.date).label("max_date"))
           .join(Part, Production.parts)
           .join(Output, Part.output)
           .filter(and_(Output.some_attr1 == attr1,
                        Output.some_attr2 == attr2,
                        Production.date<=DATE1))
           .group_by(Output.id)
           .subquery()
)
```

Ok, That query seems to work ...

2/ But, i would like to join these results with additional columns of `Output` and `Production` tables (+ apply filter on `Production.flag`).

I do not find how to do it !!!

Newbie in sqlalchemy, i will appreciate any advice or help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the query:

```
subquery2 = (
    session.query(Production.id,
                  Output.extra_attr1,
                  Production.other_attr1)
            .join(Part, Production.parts)              
            .join(Output, Part.output)
            .filter(and_(subquery1.c.max_date == Productions.date,
                         subquery1.c.id_output == Output.id,
                         Production.flag==BOOL1))
            .all()
     )
```